# mssql_query accent

Tags: php, sql-server

I hava  a problem with this mssql_query in PHP :

```
$query = 'SELECT Ville FROM tblLstManufacturiers where province = "Québec"';
```

The result is empty because I have an accent in Québec

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Ville
FROM tblLstManufacturiers
WHERE province = N'Québec' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, confused with MySQL

Comment: It'S not working, but I use the utf8_decode function on my query and it's working. Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
Select Ville
From tblLstManufacturiers
where province like '%Québec%'
```

If it is a normal textfield this should work.